# Google translate api, Requests from this ios client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked

Tags: ios, swift, google-translate

I got this error message "Requests from this ios client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked" by calling translate api, I have set to ios app and my bundle id on the web. Please help
[image]

```
    let TRANSLATE_API = "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2"
    let GOOGLE_CLOUD_API_KEY = "<API_KEY>"

    let urlParams:[String : Any] = [
        "target": target,
        "q": textToTranslate,
        "key": GOOGLE_CLOUD_API_KEY,
        "source": source]

    let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
    let headers:[String : String] = ["Content-Type": "application/json", "X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier": bundleIdentifier]

    // Fetch Request
    let urlString = TRANSLATE_API

    // Fetch Request
    Alamofire.request(urlString, parameters: urlParams)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { (response) in

            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                if response.result.error != nil {
                    completion(false, response.result.error! as! String)
                }

                if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                    if let data = json["data"] as? [String: Any] {
                        if let translations = data["translations"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                            let translatedTextDict = translations[0]
                            if let result = translatedTextDict["translatedText"] as? String {
                                completion(true, result)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break

            case .failure(_):
                completion(false, (response.result.error?.localizedDescription)!)
                break
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and after debugging, I found out the problem,

the API key works if you add it to the url, so the change your request to something like:

```
let BASE_URL = URL(string: "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2")!
Alamofire.request(BASE_URL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
```

I don't know why removing the header "Content Type" affects it.

Also a Tip: never share your keys publicly, and don't put it like that in your code, especially if you're hosting it on a public repository. Put it in a gitignored file and read it when your app starts, or set an environment variable.

Let me know if you have follow up questions.